# Please I need some help about this Linear Algebra problem. How can I do it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ a inner product space with finite dimention and let $\beta=\{ v_{1}, ... ,v_{n} \}$ an orthonormal basis for $V$. Let $T$ a linear operator over $V$ and let $A=(a_{ij})$ a matrix of $T$ in the $\beta$ basis. Prove that $(a_{ij})=\langle v_{i}, T(v_{j}) \rangle$

Comment: In your very last equality, there should be no parentheses in the left side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,  $\;Tv_j\;$ is the $\;j\,$-th **column** of $\;(a_{ij})\;$, so

$$\;\langle v_i,\,Tv_j\rangle=\left\langle v_i,\,\sum_{k=1}^na_{kj}v_k\right\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{kj}\langle v_i,\,v_k\rangle=a_{ij}$$

assuming the space is real, otherwise in the rightmost expression it must be $\;\overline{a_{ij}}\;$ and also conjugate in the sum before it...but then you wouldn't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the matrix of $T$ relative to the given basis, you have to express $T(v_j)$ as linear combination of the basis elements and the coefficients will form the $j$th column of the matrix, in the order specified by the basis.

If $w$ is any vector, then
$$
w=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,w\rangle v_i
$$
Indeed, we know that $w=\sum_{k=1}^n c_kv_k$ and orthonormality yields
$$
\langle v_i,w\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\langle v_i,v_k\rangle=c_i
$$
In particular
$$
T(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,T(v_j)\rangle v_i
$$
Thus the $j$th column of the matrix is
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1,T(v_j)\rangle \\
\langle v_2,T(v_j)\rangle \\
\vdots\\
\langle v_n,T(v_j)\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
Thus the matrix has indeed as the entry at place $(i,j)$ the inner product $\langle v_i,T(v_j)\rangle$.